# How to use access token to access Yahoo Fantasy Sports API

Tags: java, api, oauth, yql, yahoo-api

I've been trying to make an Android app (Java) that accesses Yahoo Fantasy Sports API data. I figured out the OAuth Authentication flow and my app is currently able to obtain the `access_token` that is used to get a user's private data. That access token is then stored to a class variable.

How do I actually turn that code into data?
An example query URL given by Yahoo in their documentation https://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide/GettingStarted.html) is

> https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20fantasysports.leagues%20where%20league_key%3D'238.l.627060'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=

That league is private and needs authentication to view. What I don't get is, the URL to access it does not incorporate the security `access_code` anywhere, so it's no surprise that whenever I try to go to that URL it says I do not have a high enough authentication level. How do I access the data *using* the access code?

Comment: I've had trouble with fantasy YQL as well and ending up using the fantasysports API, but for this I would try taking out `/public` in the URL and sending the `access_token` simply as a query parameter.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?